# Spring Data with JPA and @Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a SpringBoot app and an interface that extends from `PagingAndSortingRepository`

with this method

```
@Query(value = "select cp.price, cp.update_date from t_hotel_price cp where cp.hotel_id = ?1 and cp.update_date between ?2 and NOW() order by cp.price ASC LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
Object[] getMaxPriceAndDate (Long hotelId, Date aggregationDate);
```

and from the JunitTests

```
Object[] priceAndDate = hotelPriceService.getMaxPriceAndDate(currency.getId(),DateUtils.weeklyDate());  

        System.out.println 
            (priceAndDate[0]);

        System.out.println 
            (priceAndDate[1]);
```

expecting the price in priceAndDate[0] and the date in priceAndDate[1]

but instead I got a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`

Comment: What happens if you debug that code? Could you dump `priceAndDate` to see what it contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see below modified code :

Method:

```
@Query(value = "select cp.price, cp.update_date from t_hotel_price cp where cp.hotel_id = ?1 and cp.update_date between ?2 and NOW() order by cp.price ASC LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object> getMaxPriceAndDate (Long hotelId, Date aggregationDate);
```

JunitTests:

```
List<Object> priceAndDates = hotelPriceService.getMaxPriceAndDate(currency.getId(),DateUtils.weeklyDate());  
Object[] priceAndDate = (Object[])priceAndDates.get(0);

        System.out.println 
            (priceAndDate[0]);
        System.out.println 
            (priceAndDate[1]);
```

Hope this will helps you..

Comment: Before getting priceAndDates.get(0), add check if priceAndDates.size() > 0. And instead of casting to Object[] or using List<Object>, you could better have a model class, with proper type safety, like List<HotelPrice>.